# the image is not falling in start menu. Pygame

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

I have this code here that in the start menu I want to have some images falling from the sky, but its not working. I have tried many things but they didn't work.

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

display_width= 1000
display_height= 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 112)

x=0
y=0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Name")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_objects(text, font, color):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

Stmenpic = pygame.image.load("Start_menu_sky_back_ground.png")

def StartMenPic(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(Stmenpic, (x,y) )

def Title_Of_Game(text):
    Title_Text = pygame.font.Font("ARDESTINE.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, Title_Text, blue)
    TextRect.center = ((500),(100))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update

Baby_1=pygame.image.load("Baby_1.png")

def things(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(Baby_1,(x, y ))

x_change = 0

def Title_of_Game():
    Title_Of_Game("Title")

def Start_Menu():

    StartMenu=True
    while StartMenu:
        x = 0
        y = 0
        x_change = 0

        thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
        thing_starty = -600
        thing_speed = 7
        thing_width= 30
        thing_height=30

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        Title_of_Game()
        x_change=0

        x+= x_change

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

StartMenPic(0, 0)
Start_Menu()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

It is probably very obvious but I am only starting out so I need a lot of help. Thank you for all the help in this question.
Now I have a problem with the block, it always spawns in random locations but doesn't go down.

This is the main part of this code:

```
    pygame.init()

    display_width= 1000
    display_height= 600

    Startmenpic = pygame.image.load("Start_menu_sky_back_ground.png")
    stmenpic = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
def Start_Menu():
    thing_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randrange(display_width), -60, 30, 30)
    thing_speed = 7

    StartMenu = True

    while StartMenu:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        Title_of_Game()

        thing_rect.y += thing_speed

        if thing_rect.y > display_height:
            thing_rect.y = 0 - thing_rect.height
            thing_rect.x = random.randrange(display_width)

            gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
            gameDisplay.blit(stmenpic, thing_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

    StartMenPic(0, 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    Start_Menu()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

    stmenpic.fill((0, 200, 50))
```

Comment: What do you want to make fall? Look at my answer below.

Comment: I want to make the baby_1 picture to fall. The Stmenpic is the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define the position and velocity variables in the `while` loop or they will be reset each frame (iteration of the loop). Instead, define them outside of the loop and change the positions inside the loop by adding the speed.

I also recommend using a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object instead of the separate `thing_startx`, `thing_starty`, `thing_width` and `thing_height` variables:

```
# Pass the top left coordinates, the width and the height.
thing_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randrange(display_width), -60, 30, 30)
```

Then update its y-coordinate by adding the speed each frame:

```
thing_rect.y += thing_speed
```

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
import pygame
import random


pygame.init()

display_width = 1000
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

stmenpic = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
stmenpic.fill((0, 200, 50))


def start_menu():
    thing_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randrange(display_width), -60, 30, 30)
    thing_speed = 7

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # Move the rect downwards.
        thing_rect.y += thing_speed
        # Reset the position of the rect when it leaves the screen.
        if thing_rect.y > display_height:
            thing_rect.y = 0 - thing_rect.height
            thing_rect.x = random.randrange(display_width)

        gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
        gameDisplay.blit(stmenpic, thing_rect)  # Blit the image at the rect.
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


start_menu()
pygame.quit()
```

If you want multiple falling objects, just put some rects into a list and use `for` loops to update and draw them.

Comment: I copied the code but it just shows a grey back ground.

Comment: There should be a falling green rect (the `stmenpic` surface). Have you modified anything?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I forgot to add a dot between the thing_rect and y. But the green square just spawns randomly on the top and doesn't go down. Also do you know how to change the green square into a picture?

Comment: Just load the image with `pygame.image.load`.

Comment: My thing doesn't go down. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Please show me the code (you could temporarily add it to the question or post it on a site like pastebin.com). Or better just ask a new question. I could also open a chatroom, but I think you need at least 20 reputation to talk there.

Comment: The line `gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))` and the following three lines should not be in the `if thing_rect.y > display_height:` clause. Dedent them once.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you and sorry that this is off topic but do you know how I could make the "rectangles" be randomly chosen.

Comment: Better post a new question, but try to find a solution on your own first and add your attempts to the question. You could put your images/pygame.Surfaces into a list and use `random.choice` to pick one. Then call [`image.get_rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) to create a rect with the size of the image and put the image and the rect into a list. I mean something similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188563/pygame-elements-with-different-speed/52235124#52235124).